# lock() method acquires locks on which object?

Tags: java, concurrency, locks

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class LockTest {
    Lock lck=new ReentrantLock();

    public void lockIt(){
        lck.lock();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            System.out.println("i : "+ i);
            try{Thread.sleep(200);} catch (Exception e){}
        }
        lck.unlock();
    }

    public void test()
    {
        synchronized(this)     **// mark 1**
        {
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
            {
                System.out.println("val is"+j);
                try{Thread.sleep(200);}catch (Exception e){}
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LockTest obj=new LockTest();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                obj.lockIt();
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                obj.test();
            }
         }).start();

     }
}
```

}
// In above case when we say lck.lock(); then lock is acquired on
which object actually ? is it "this" or the "lck" itself ?

even if the lock gets acquired on either of "this" or "lck" object
then how diff. threads are able to enter into the critical sections
locked by the same "this" or "lck" object.

case 1: when we use synchronized(this) at mark1..
case 2: when we use synchronized(lck ) at mark 1..

in both the cases both the loops runs in parallel.

Comment: Have a look at http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/. The answer to your question is that the lock method ensures, that the locked block can only be accessed by one thread. It does not actually lock on the actual `object`, thus `synchronized` is a different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock obtained by `lck.lock()` (which is on the `lck` object) is completely unrelated to the lock obtained by `synchronized(this)` or `synchronized(lck)`.

If you want to protect critical sections, then all threads have to use the same locking mechanism (and the same lock).

`java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` is a different mechanism introduced for cases where the `synchronized` keyword is not flexible enough. In particular, the `synchronized` keyword automatically obtains and releases locks as execution enters and leaves a block. It is not possible there to obtain a lock in one method, store it somewhere, leave the method and release the lock sometime later. With the `Lock` object you can do these things (and it also offers lock wait timeouts, whereas `synchronized` will potentially block forever).

Answer (score 0):

@Thilo has answered most of it, just to add one point from your code, **ensure that you are unlocking in the finally block** as shown below, otherwise, there is a possibility that you will be ending up with a **dead lock**.

```
public void lockIt(){
    lck.lock();
  try {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        System.out.println("i : "+ i);
        try{Thread.sleep(200);}catch (Exception e){}
    }
  } finally { //important
    if(lck != null) {
        lck.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```